# SQL where condition return all records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one PHP model function (far more complicated than this one in example). The example is only to simplify things.

```
public function findProduct($size, $material, $category) {
    $sql = new Sql($this->dbAdapter);
    $select = $sql->select(array('p' =>'products'));
    $select->where(array('size'=>$size, 'material'=>$material,'category'=>$category));
 }
```

The function works of course. Now, I would like to use the same function in case when I don't need $material query (when I want products for all materials).

Is there any value which I could put in `$material=?;` to get products for all materials in db table?That's what would suit me the best.

The solution when i put `$material ='';` and then in function check

```
if($material =='') {
    $select->where(array('size'=>$size, 'category'=>$category));
 } else {
    $select->where(array('size'=>$size, 'material'=>$material,'category'=>$category));
}
```

complicates function (which is already enough complicated and long) and I don't want to use.

Comment: Which library are you using to plug to PHP to SQL? You're not writing raw SQL queries...

Comment: Normally this would be done by adding an OR clause along with the `material` which is just a flag you can set.  Something like `(material = ? OR 1 = ?)` and in your code the second parameter would be some kind of "return all materials" flag.  But how would you add an OR clause with whatever data access library you're using?

Comment: If you need to have 2 different where clauses than you are going to have to do something to test which one you need